# Integer.parseInt() saying "invalid int" in Marhsmallow 6.0.1, Its working perfectly in Pre-Marshamallow versions

Tags: java, android, integer, android-6.0-marshmallow

I know really very well that the value i am parsing as an **Integer** here is a **Long** value.

> **The Question is :** Why its working in Pre-Marshmallow ??

Here is my code:

```
public void print(long mili) {
    Long serverUptimeSeconds =
            (mili - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000;


    String serverUptimeText =
            String.format("%02d%02d%02d%02d",
                    Math.abs(serverUptimeSeconds) / 86400,
                    (Math.abs(serverUptimeSeconds) % 86400) / 3600,
                    ((Math.abs(serverUptimeSeconds) % 86400) % 3600) / 60,
                    ((Math.abs(serverUptimeSeconds) % 86400) % 3600) % 60
            );

        // compiler is giving error at this line in Marshmallow 6.0.1 only
        tv.setValue(Integer.parseInt(serverUptimeText), false);

}
```

My Function:

```
public void setValue(int value, boolean withAnimation) {

    mCurrentValue = value;
    int tempValue = value;

    for (int i = 7; i > 0; --i) 
    {
        int factor = (int) Math.pow(10, i);
        int digitVal = (int) Math.floor(tempValue / factor);
        tempValue -= (digitVal * factor);

        mDigitSpinners[i].setDigit(digitVal, withAnimation);
        changeAnimationCompleteCounter(withAnimation);
    }

    mDigitSpinners[0].setDigit(tempValue, withAnimation);
    changeAnimationCompleteCounter(withAnimation);

}
```

Stacktrace :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.srk/com.srk.DayPSearchActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "16905104155"
>                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
>                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
>                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
>                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "16905104155"
>                                                                at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
>                                                                at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:413)
>                                                                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)

Comment: please post stacktrace and try printing serverUptimeText in your log

Comment: The problem is, Its working fine in Lollipop and jellybean @DeadpoolDude

Comment: Again, post stacktrace from logCat and optionally print out the value of serverUptimeText

Comment: Paste stacktrace here. You can post this in Android issue [tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Developer%20bug%20report).

Comment: @jankigadhiya It is simply impossible that 16905104155 can be integer even in Pre-Marshmallow, check again.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt("16905104155")` crashes on Android 5.1 and Android 4.3. I know this, because I just tested it, and got `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "16905104155"` in both cases. You are welcome to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates that `Integer.parseInt("16905104155")` actually does work prior to Android 6.0.

Comment: Sorry All it was a Date Parsing Exception so the values in Marshmallow and  Lollipop were Different @DeadpoolDude You are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You try to parse a int `16905104155`, but it is a long.

Try to parse it as a long, `Long.parseLong(serverUptimeText)`

Comment: But Its working fine in Lollipop and jellybean. I have tried `Long.parseLong()` but i am not getting the desired result.

Comment: Maybe it was, back then when you tried it, a lower value and was it able to parse as `int`

Comment: The value is same in both cases.

Comment: @jankigadhiya imposible 16905104155 cannot be an int, it is long

Comment: I agree its a Long.Then why it is not giving error in Pre-Marshmallow ?? @DeadpoolDude

Comment: @jankigadhiya check Pre-Marshmallow again and print the value it absolutely cannot be the same

Answer (score 3):

If you see [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) it will be

> 2^31-1 =  2147483647.

But whatever you are having the value which is 16905104155 > 2147483647.

Use Long instead.

Edit: If I see log-cat error : `Integer.java:413` where method having the signature like this.

```
private static int parse(String string, int offset, int radix, boolean negative) throws NumberFormatException {
}
```

But the correct method as per your call should be

```
public static int parseInt(String string, int radix) throws NumberFormatException {
}
```

Please recheck once.

Comment: I agree its a Long.Then why it is not giving error in Pre-Marshmallow ??

Comment: i haven't passed any argument its just `Integer.parseInt(serverUptimeText)`.

Answer (score 2):

There is your problem

```
Invalid int: "16905104155"
```

which is 16,905,104,155 (type long) and that is over the int limit (2,147,483,647).